# Display static block title

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

In the footer of my theme I've placed a static block, with the code below. But it only echo's the content of the block and not the title, how do I also get the title?

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-column-1">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-column-1</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike CMS pages, the block title is only used as reference for the administrator. It is not supposed to be used in the front. So the best way to give the block a title is to add a  tag in the block itself.